# Working with dates in R, Error in charToDate(x)

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I transformed dates in my data frame into a standard format "YYYY-MM-DD" with lubridate:

```
df$diagnosis_year <- lubridate::ymd(df$diagnosis_year, truncated = 2L)
```

Now I'd like to count the number of rows where the df$diagnosis_year != NA and another parameter is "1".

I tried this:

```
nrow(df[df$diagnosis_year != 'NA' & df$smoker_status == '1', ])
```

but always get an error message:

```
***Error in charToDate(x) : 
  Zeichenkette ist nicht in einem eindeutigen Standardformat***
```

I'd be very grateful for help!!!

My data frame to reproduce:

```
df = data.frame (diagnosis_year  = c("1999", "2005", "1998", "2022", "2001"),
                  smoker_status = c("1", "0", "1", "1", "99"), sex = c("2", "2", "1", "2", "1")
                  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to check if an element is missing, don't use `== NA`, but the built-in function `is.na`:

```r
nrow(df[is.na(df$diagnosis_year) & df$smoker_status == '1', ]) 
#[1] 0
```

---

To understand your error, note that first a missing value is noted `NA` in R, not `'NA'`, i.e. `NA` is not a string (character), but a special operator (check `?NA`). By comparing (with `!=`) dates with a string, you are forcing `!=` to convert the string `'NA'` to be converted to a date, in order for the comparison to be possible; but of course this does not work, hence the error.